# Kubernetes rewrite-target paths for appending path to match

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm, kubernetes-ingress, nginx-ingress

I'm using the OSS `ingress-nginx` Ingress controller and trying to create a rewrite-target rule such that I can append a path string before my string match.

If I wanted to create a rewrite rule with regex that matches `/matched/path` and rewrites that to `/prefix/matched/path`, how might I be able to do that?

I've tried something like the following but it's no good, and I'm just confused about the syntax of this ingress definition:

```
metadata:
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: nginx
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /$2
spec:
  rules:
    - path: /(/prefix/)(/|$)(/matched/path)(.*)
      backend:
        serviceName: webapp1
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> If I wanted to create a rewrite rule with regex that matches
> `/matched/path` and rewrites that to `/prefix/matched/path`, how might
> I be able to do that?

In order to achieve this you have add `/prefix` into your `rewrite-target`.
Here's a working example with ingress syntax from k8s v1.18:

```yaml
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: example-ingress-v118
  annotations:
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /prefix/$1
spec:
  rules:
    http:
       paths:
       - path: /(matched/path/?.*)
        backend:
          serviceName: test
          servicePort: 80
```

Since the syntax for the new ingress changed in 1.19 (see [release notes](https://kubernetes.io/docs/setup/release/notes/) and some small info at the end) I`m placing also an example with it:

```yaml
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: example-ingress-v119
  annotations:
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /prefix/$1
spec:
  rules:
  - http:
      paths:
      - path: /(matched/path/?.*)
        pathType: Prefix
        backend:
          service:
            name: test
            port:
              number: 80
```

Here is a test with http echo server:

```
➜  ~ curl 172.17.0.4/matched/path 
{
  "path": "/prefix/matched/path",
  "headers": {
    "host": "172.17.0.4",
    "x-request-id": "011585443ebc6adcf913db1c506abbe6",
    "x-real-ip": "172.17.0.1",
    "x-forwarded-for": "172.17.0.1",
    "x-forwarded-host": "172.17.0.4",
    "x-forwarded-port": "80",
    "x-forwarded-proto": "http",
    "x-scheme": "http",
    "user-agent": "curl/7.52.1",
    "accept": "*/*"
  },
```

This rule will also ignore the `/` at the end of the request:

```
➜  ~ curl 172.17.0.4/matched/path/
{
  "path": "/prefix/matched/path/",
  "headers": {
    "host": "172.17.0.4",
    "x-request-id": "0575e9022d814ba07457395f78dbe0fb",
    "x-real-ip": "172.17.0.1",
    "x-forwarded-for": "172.17.0.1",
    "x-forwarded-host": "172.17.0.4",
    "x-forwarded-port": "80",
    "x-forwarded-proto": "http",
    "x-scheme": "http",
    "user-agent": "curl/7.52.1",
    "accept": "*/*"
  },
```

---

Worth to mention some notable differences/changes in the new ingress syntax:

- `spec.backend` -> `spec.defaultBackend`
- `serviceName` -> `service.name`
- `servicePort` -> `service.port.name` (for string values)
- `servicePort` -> `service.port.number` (for numeric values) `pathType` no longer has a default value in v1; "Exact", "Prefix", or
  "ImplementationSpecific" must be specified Other Ingress API updates
- backends can now be resource or service backends
- `path` is no longer required to be a valid regular expression (#89778,
  @cmluciano) [SIG API Machinery, Apps, CLI, Network and Testing]